# Use Javascript / JQuery to dynamically create multiple HTML buttons with different click event handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, dynamic, click

I am trying to use Javascript / JQuery to dynamically create several HTML buttons, each of which does something different when it is clicked.

My first attempt looked like this:

```
function myFunc( target_div, num_buttons ) {
    var buttons="";
    for ( var i=0; i<num_buttons; i++ ) {
        buttons += '<input type="button" id="button_'+i+'" value="button_'+i+'"></input>';
    }
    target_div.html( buttons );
    var doButtonPress = function( i ) {
        alert( i ); // I actually do something more complicated here, but it's not important now
    }
    for ( var i=0; i<num_buttons; i++ ) {
        $('#button_'+i).click( function() { doButtonPress(i); } );
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work because (I think) when the click event happens, doButtonPress is always passed the current value of i in myFunc's scope, not - as I intended - the value i had when the click event was defined. Thus the value passed to doButtonPress is always equal to num_buttons regardless of which button is pressed. So I then tried this instead:

```
$('#button_'+i).click( new Function( "doButtonPress("+i+");" ) );
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work either - I get a message "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: returnResult". I assume that's because the Function constructor's arg value isn't parsed until the click event happens, and at that time I'm already outside of myFunc's scope so doButtonPress is undefined? Am I getting this right so far?

So ... what do I do? :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code didn't work because of the scope of variable `i` which would be `num_button` always inside the handler. You can fix it by wrapping it inside a `closure` but how about simplifying it by adding a class and making use of the id of the button.

```
function myFunc( target_div, num_buttons ) {
    var buttons="";
    for ( var i=0; i<num_buttons; i++ ) {
        //                             added class ----------------v
        buttons += '<input type="button" id="button_'+i+'" class="mybuttons" value="button_'+i+'"></input>';
    }
    target_div.html( buttons );
    var doButtonPress = function( i ) {
        alert( i ); // I actually do something more complicated here, but it's not important now
    }

    //yes, mybuttons exist 
    $('.mybuttons').click(function () {
         doButtonPress(this.id.replace('button_', ''));
         //this.id.replace('button_', '') <- returns i value
    });
}
```

Comment: Great - thanks! I like this solution because it allows doButtonPress to not know anything about the buttons, as intended. Although I guess I should change the name if that's what I intend! :)

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to assign a `data` attribute to each button which can then be read when the button is clicked. This will then avoid the need for unnecessary (and ugly) incremental `id` attributes. Something like this:

```
function myFunc($target_div, num_buttons) {
    var buttons = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < num_buttons; i++) {
        buttons.push($('<input type="button" class="button" data-id="' + i + '" value="button ' + i + '" />'));
    }
    $target_div.append(buttons);

    var doButtonPress = function() {
        alert($(this).data('id'));
    }

    $(".button").click(doButtonPress);
}
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/v8kju/)

Comment: Ah, OK, so when doButtonPress is called, this will automatically refer to the button that was clicked to invoke it? Cool. Thanks!

Comment: @baixiwei no problem. Don't forget to click the green tick to the left if this answer helped.