# What is the better way to combine this html into one by using array or variable?

Tags: php, html

what is the better way to combine these code into one? They have the same class, id have the same prefix name, use one, two , three to differentiate them. I am thinking about using something like, `array=('one','two','three')`, but then, it will become `array[0],array[1],` still cannot make them become one. Appreciate your help.

```html
<div class="user_voting" id="user_diet_one">
  <div class="vote_title" id="diet_one"><span class="title_text">one:</span>
   
  </div><!-- vote_title-->
  
  <div class="my_vote_body" id="my_vote_one"> 
  <input type="button" class="user_save_button" value="Save"/>
     
 </div><!-- my_vote_body-->
    </div><!-- user_voting one-->

<div class="user_voting" id="user_diet_two">
  <div class="vote_title" id="diet_two"><span class="title_text">two:</span>
   
  </div><!-- vote_title-->
  
  <div class="my_vote_body" id="my_vote_two"> 
  <input type="button" class="user_save_button" value="Save"/>
     
 </div><!-- my_vote_body-->
    </div><!-- user_voting two-->


<div class="user_voting" id="user_diet_three">
  <div class="vote_title" id="diet_three"><span class="title_text">three:</span>
   
  </div><!-- vote_title-->
  
  <div class="my_vote_body" id="my_vote_three"> 
  <input type="button" class="user_save_button" value="Save"/>
     
 </div><!-- my_vote_body-->
    </div><!-- user_voting-->
```

Comment: Have you at least tried something?

Comment: If your purpose is simply to vote on something, I would use either radio buttons or a dropdown box so they can select their option (or options) and submit it as a form. That'll make it simple and shorten it. It also gives them a chance to change their mind prior to submitting.

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13199303/1837329

Comment: I edit the question again, I hope it will not people misunderstand it again. Thanks for you time anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php

$arr = Array("one", "two", "three");

foreach ($arr as $key)
{
?>
<div class="user_voting" id="user_diet_"<?php echo $key; ?> >
<div class="vote_title" id="diet_"<?php echo $key; ?>><span class="title_text"><?php echo $key; ?>:</span>

    </div>

    <div class="my_vote_body" id="my_vote_"<?php echo $key; ?>> 
    <input type="button" class="user_save_button" value="Save"/>

</div>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
```

This way there is lesser code since you make use of array but it may still not be an optimal solution though depending on what you're trying to do.